# No USB devices or running emulator detected

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very new to Android development. I am trying to create and run an app from tutorial - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

But while running app it is showing me "No USB devices or running emulator detected" in Select deployment target dialog.

**Background and what I tried:**

1. I am using Lenovo K4 note Vibe.
2. Android version 5.1
3. I have enabled USB Debugging from my phone also checked "Enable OEM unlock"
4. I have selected USB "MTP" as connection mode when I connected my phone to machine.
5. I am using windows 7 and Android studio version 2.3.2
6. My device appears in "Device Manager" of my system i.e. It is installed properly.
7. When I connect my phone to my system it shows AutoPlay dialog, asking to run "Run Lenovo_suite.exe", I tried to see if my deice appears in Studio when I allow to run that app, but still no luck
8. I also tried by checking and unchecking "Enable ADB Integration" from Android studio, still no luck
9. I have already installed Android SDK for verion 5.1
10. I have also tried installing "Google USB driver".
11. I also tried connecting my device to all of my machine port
12. I am tried using Emulator, but it is really very slow on my machine, it takes around 2-3 hours just to boot. So, I am using my phone.

Your assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated

Comment: Try restarting your computer and android studio with refresh cache

Comment: Hours to boot? By the way. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator/18720169

Comment: Guys, I got the solution, which I posted below. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your support guys. After 2 hours of struggle I found below:

When I connect my device to the machine, it shows me a AutoRun dialog to Run Lenovo_suite.exe(Which I mentioned in my question), but instead of auto running, I explored that newly created lenovo drive, which had 2-3 setup exe's(usb drivers and magicPlus), I installed both and restarted my machine. When I run MagicPlus software, it helped me to Authorize USB debugging with some kind of fingerprints. And now my device appeared in studio.

Answer (score 0):

this problem just happen when your USB connection mode is not work in debug mode, Like:

`File Transfer` Or `MIDI device`

The `Charging Only` is Work in android 5 and above

GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

a addition to above answer i think if you try to debug it , you will get better result since android if had problem throw a error that says restart adb.exe , 
another thing whats your hardware config ?
and have you tried genymotion , i prefer it over android virtual device , working with a real device is better , but i prefer when to concentrate on monitor have device on it ;)

Answer (score 0):

As per My experience many device not connect 
So you need to try this Windows Software to detected your android phone

Install it on your windows system [PDANET+](http://pdanet.co/a/)